# Binding HTML without ng-bind-html attribute?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In order to bind HTML I have to use `ng-bind-html`, and sanitise it with `$sce.trustAsHtml(...)`

What I want to know, is there a way to bind the HTML without the attribute?

Most of my binding is done using `{{...}}` and then the moment I want to bind HTML I have to fall back to the attribute, so I'm hoping there's a way to use the expression instead.

Comment: You can't use `{{...}}` to bind HTML. It's not how it is implemented. What's the problem with using `ngBindHtml` ?

Comment: It's there to stop hordes of russian hackers from wtfpwning your site with XSS attacks.

Comment: @ExpertSystem - there's nothing wrong with it, I guess I could make a filter for it and so {{ value | unsafe }}, it's just I've used {{}} everywhere, and the 1 place I need HTML I have to call back to a different syntax.

Comment: @ivarni - I get that, I just thought there would be a nicer way to do it using the expression like {{*value}} to imply that in this 1 case I expect HTML.

Comment: Well yeah, some syntactic sugar is always nice. I'm not aware of anything like that though, so I think a feature request to the angular team is the path to take.